# Tanget of differential equation in a point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, tangent-line

My teacher and I have been completely stumped by a differential equation. We solved it in two different ways, and now we aren't sure which result is correct.

The differential of the function `f` is the solution to the differential equation `(dy(x))/(dx) = 2 y(x) - 1`. Solve f so the tangent in the point `(2, f(2)` has the equation `y=2x-5/2`.

The general solution for `f(x) = 1/2 + e^(2 x) * k`. Now we get to the point of contention. My teacher solved the specific solution for `f(2)=3/2` while I solved it for `f'(2)=3/2`. I'm pretty confident in my solution, but not enough to make a convincing argument. Any thoughts?

Comment: You might want to double check your general solution. The differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=2y-1$ should have a solution of the form $y=\frac 12+ke^{2x}$.

Comment: You're right. It was a typo from when I entered it here.

Comment: Solving for $f'(2)=3/2$ is a bad idea, as the slope of the tangent is $2$. This is your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'(x)=2y(x)-1$$ has the solution $$y(x)=Ce^{2x}+\frac12.$$

The tangent at $x=2$ is

$$Y-y(2)=y'(2)(X-2),$$
$$Y-\left(Ce^{2\cdot2}+\frac12\right)=2Ce^{2\cdot2}(X-2).$$

We identify the coefficients with the given ones and get the system

$$\begin{cases}2Ce^4=2,\\-4Ce^4+Ce^4+\dfrac12=-\dfrac52\end{cases},$$ which is compatible. For both equations, $C=e^{-4}$.

Hence

$$y(x)=e^{2x-4}+\frac12.$$

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? When I solve `f` for `f(2)=2` I get the result `f(x)=1/2 + 3/2×e^(2 x)/e^4`. That result is the same as when I solve for `f'(x)=3/2`, where the `3/2` is a reduction of `2*2-5/2`.

Comment: @Herbstein: by the equation of the tangent, $y(2)=3/2$ and by the differential equation, $y'(2)=2y(2)-1=2$. You must be confusing $y(2)$ and $y'(2)$. **The slope of the tangent is $2$.**